# segmentation fault in this code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void sort(int a[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for (j = i; j < n - 1; j++)
      if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
        a[j] = a[j + 1] - (a[j + 1] = a[j]);
}

int call(int i, int hit, int t, int h[], int n, int count)
{
  static int max = 0;

  if (t <= 0)
  {
    if (count > max)
      max = count;
    return max;
  }

  if (h[i] > 0)
  {
    h[i] -= hit;
    if (h[i] <= 0)
      count++;
    max = call((i + 1) % n, hit, t - 1, h, n, count);//this is line where illegal access to memory is being made
    count--;
    h[i] += hit;
  }

  max = call((i + 1) % n, hit, t, h, n, count);
  return max;
}

int getMaxMonsters(int n, int hit, int t, int h[]) {
  sort(h, n);
  int m = call(0, hit, t, h, n, 0);
  return m;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int hit;
  int t;
  scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &hit, &t);
  int h[100000];

  for (int h_i = 0; h_i < n; h_i++) {
    scanf("%d", &h[h_i]);
  }

  int result = getMaxMonsters(n, hit, t, h);
  printf("%d\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

This code computes in the maximum number of monsters that can be killed.

- `n` is no. of monsters
- `hit` is hit value
- `h[]` contains health value of each monster
- `t` is the total time available

So, the maximum number of monsters have to be killed in t seconds and and only one monster per second.
I am getting segmentation fault for illegal access of memory. Unable to understand how am I crossing the array limits.

Comment: Please edit your question. Tag the language you are using. Add a question. Explain what happens and what is wrong. Explain what happened when you ran the code in a debugger line by line checking for errors.

Comment: You don't seem to have any array access on your offending line. Try looking at your call stack. Is there anything unusual in it?

Comment: I've tweaked the code formatting slightly.

Comment: I don't get illegal memory access errors, but I do get a stack overflow because `call` goes into infinite recursion. Perhaps you should share the exact parameter values you were using that trigger the crash.

Comment: `a[j] = a[j + 1] - (a[j + 1] = a[j]);` : there could be a sequence point missing here .

Comment: @joop Right - and in any case, that code is needlessly cryptic. Anyone who thinks such code is clever - it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your debugger or use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).
it automatically detects memory management bugs. it also profiles your program in detail.

it is too simple to use Valgrind.